# issue with converting the model from colab to tf.keras h5 model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras

I'm having a really hard time converting this model to s h5 model so I can then convert it to Tensorflow lite  Someone managed to do that. I shared  the colab here: 
I really appreciate any help that I can get.
here is my colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZON8lvha8sI9ZCJEF0Ad8au2NNc9sUkU

I used this approach:

```py
from docproduct.models import MedicalQAModelwithBert

medical_qa_model = MedicalQAModelwithBert(
        config_file=os.path.join(
            pretrained_path, 'bert_config.json'),
        checkpoint_file=os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'biobert_model.ckpt'))

medical_qa_model.save("model.h5")
```

The error that I get is

> NotImplementedError: The `save` method requires the model to be a Functional model or a Sequential model. It does not work for subclassed models, because such models are defined via the body of a Python method, which isn't safely serializable. Consider using `save_weights`, in order to save the weights of the model.

I can `save_weights` but then I will have issue with converting with tflite because that requires the whole model. Any one have any suggestions how to solve this issue ?

My ultimate goal is to convert the model to tflite.

Thanks

**Update:**

It seems the issue is that they make their own subclass of Model and do not implement save().

https://github.com/re-search/DocProduct/blob/master/docproduct/models.py#L62

Is there any workaround to be able to convert the model without training it from scratch?

Comment: I don't know much about tflite, but the error seems pretty straightforward. The model you are using (`MedicalQAModelwithBert`) is a subclass of a Keras model type, and thus cannot be saved to HDF5. Looking at [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert), there are a few alternatives to that (using a `SavedModel`, freeze the graph or just take it from a session). Look up the [Python](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api) and [command line](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples) guides to see what may suit you best.

Comment: Try serialising and saving it as json

Comment: `model_json = model.to_json();
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)`

Comment: and load it as:

```
from keras.models import model_from_json;
json_file = open('model.json', 'r');
loaded_model_json = json_file.read();
json_file.close();
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json);
```


But this may also require to save the weights separately.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa thank you for your comments. The model is custom and when use `model_json = medical_qa_model.to_json()` I get the `NotImplementedError: `